# Get flexbox column wrap to use full width and minimize height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with a fixed width and variable height. I'm filling the container with an unknown amount of elements.
I'd like the elements to arrange themselves in columns, from top to bottom and then left to right.

I could use `column`, but I don't know the maximum width of the child elements, so I can't set a `column-width` or `column-count`.

I think `display: flex` with `flex-flow: column wrap` is the way to go, but if I maintain `height: auto` on the container, it will generate as a single column without wrapping elements to use all the available width.

Can I convince flexbox to use all the available width and thus minimize the container's height? 
Would you suggest a different solution?

---

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52our0eh/

Source:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>These</span>
    <span>should</span>
    <span>arrange</span>
    <span>themselves</span>
    <span>into</span>
    <span>columns,</span>
    <span>using</span>
    <span>all</span>
    <span>available</span>
    <span>width</span>
    <span>and</span>
    <span>minimizing</span>
    <span>the</span>
    <span>container's</span>
    <span>height.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    /*height: 8em;*/
}
span {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Still trying to come up with a good solution to this in 2022...!

Answer (score 1):

What you look for is more like the column rules: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52our0eh/2/)**

```
div {/* do not set column numbers rule */
    width: 100%;
    -moz-column-width:4em;
    column-width:4em;
    -moz-column-gap:0;
    column-gap:0;
    -moz-column-rule:solid 1px;
    column-rule:solid 1px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I do not know the width of the child elements beforehand, they might be more than 4em.

Comment: @Thoronwen set whatever width you think okay, or set a fixed numbers of columns. or use javascript or jquery to set/adapt a column-width on the fly.

Comment: [this article](http://zomigi.com/blog/deal-breaker-problems-with-css3-multi-columns/) still applies re multi-column properties

Answer (score 0):

I've compromised and set `height: 10em` (which seems acceptable) along with `overflow-y: auto` (to add a horizontal scrollbar in case of overflow) on the container element.

I would still like to know if there is a way to use all available width and minimize the height, though.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, your options for overflowing are hide, scroll, or wrap.  How about this version instead?  It takes any overflowing items and puts them on a second row.  Items on the second row still fill the available space, but are larger due to the smaller number of items sharing the space.

http://jsfiddle.net/52our0eh/14/

```
div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
span {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    flex:1;
}
```

Comment: Example above does not work as expected. Height is not minimal and no wrapping happened.