# Flexbox Column Grid with fit-to-height blocks

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, grid-layout

I need some help setting up a column-based grid for flexible layout.  I am hoping to use flexbox primarily, but have been unable to figure out how to implement exactly what I need.  I am also open to using a JS grid plugin, but again have not found one that meets me specific needs.

Here is a photo that illustrates what I'm hoping to build.
[Grid Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnnKR.jpg)

The most important priorities are:

1. The layout creates as many columns as possible within the master content container.
2. After organizing the content blocks in columns, resize each content block so that each column's height is uniform.
3. The height of the master content container's height scales fit content within.
4. Having the elements display in order is preferable, but not mandatory.

I also want the width of the content container to scale based on device.  So predictably when it goes down to mobile it becomes a simple one column layout.

Now I believe I can control the number of grids by setting the container width, and content block width specifically based on device. I.e. if it's on mobile the content blocks are 100% width, and if it is on desktop the container is 900px and the content blocks are 300px.

That plus flexbox should give me something that resembles this. [Flexbox Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ru0v.jpg), but only if I set a fixed height on the master container, which is not ideal.

So my question is, is there a way to setup flexbox to achieve my goals?  If, not is there JS plugin that is capable of doing this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="blocks">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="info" style="height:280px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="info" style="height:280px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="info" style="height:280px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="info" style="height:600px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="info" style="height:400px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="info" style="height:300px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#blocks{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items:flex-start;
    flex-wrap:wrap;         

    background-color: #ddd;
    width:900px;
    height:900px;
}
.info{
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    background-color: #888;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
.block{
    width:290px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 0 auto;

    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWGzej?editors=1100)

Comment: So, what have you tired so far?

Comment: I have a setup that looks much like the second illustration using Flexbox.  Ih have also tried to use Wookmark JS and Freewall JS with no success.

Comment: Then please post the code that you have tried so far so that we can help you and not write all of the code for you.

Comment: Check out this pen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWGzej?editors=1100  I have figured out how to make the block items scale to fit the container height.  However this is only because I have set the container height specifically.  I can't figure out how to prioritize using more columns, over simply stacking blocks vertically.

Comment: At this point it looks like I have the same issue as this question.  But I'm not 100% satisfied with the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446921/get-flexbox-column-wrap-to-use-full-width-and-minimize-height?rq=1